# How can I add attributes to rendered JSON from relationship without nesting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

Here's the problem: I'm using active record and returning some photo objects. The final consumer of these photo objects is going to be a mobile app.

The response needs to have thumbnail versions returned mobile developer has requested that the JSON coming back look like this..

```
{
"root_url":'http://place.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/',
"image_300":'image_300.jpg',
"image_600":'image_600.jpg',
"image_vga":'image_VGA.jpg',
"image_full":'image.jpg'
}
```

and not like this:

```
{
"root_url":'http://place.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/',
"thumbnails": {
  "image_300":'image_300.jpg',
  "image_600":'image_600.jpg',
  "image_vga":'image_VGA.jpg',
  "image_full":'image.jpg'
 }
}
```

so far the easy way is to create columns for each of the thumbnails and wow it works. I don't like getting locked into that though because if we wanted different thumbnails later it would mean adding columns to the db etc. I would much prefer to either just specify the thumbnails in the model class OR have a separate table for thumbnails with one thumb per row of the table.

I've looked at delegate, composed_of, using GROUP_CONCAT in a join.., using :method=> in to_json .. none of these look like options. Is there an easy way to do this?

Basic model example:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :thumbnails, :as => :thumbs_for #polymorphic
end

class Thumbnail < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns = name, filename
  belongs_to :thumb_for, :polymorphic => true
end
```

**So far the result looks like this** based on the answer from jesse reiss

```
def as_json(options)
  options ||= {} #even if you provide a default, it ends up as nil
  hash = super(options.merge({:include => :thumbnails}))
  if thumbs = hash.delete(:thumbnails)
    thumbs.each {|t| hash.merge!({t['name']=>t['filename']})}
  end
  hash
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can customize the json serialization of an object pretty simply using the `as_json` method.

For this, you could do :

```
def as_json(*args)
  hash = super(*args)
  hash.merge!(hash.delete("thumbnails"))
end
```

Or you could do it super manually

```
def as_json(*args)
  hash = super()
  thumbnails.each do |thumb|
    # build thumbnail json
  end
end
```

You don't have to rely on ActiveRecord's super simplistic json serialization methods.